# How can I push down page content after header?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress site.
The code works sometimes. I am highly confused as to why sometimes it adds the margin from mastHeight correctly and other times it adds extra margin. I suspect it has to do something with the page not being fully loaded when the script runs. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

this is the code i am running on the site:

```
<script>    
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     // When the window resizes
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
         // Get the height + padding + border of `#masthead`
        var mastHeight = $("#global-header-section").innerHeight();
        // Add the height to `.site-content`
        $("#et-main-area").css('margin-top', mastHeight);
    });
     // Trigger the function on document load.
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the script you have is not working as expected because the page may not be fully loaded when the script runs. To ensure that the script only runs when the page is fully loaded, you can wrap the entire script in the following way:

```
jQuery(window).on("load", function() {
  // Your script code here
});
```

This will ensure that the script only runs when all elements on the page are loaded, including images and other resources. Another issue could be that the script is being run multiple times on the same page, which can cause the margin-top value to be incorrectly calculated. To avoid this, you can wrap your script in an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) to create a closure, like this:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // When the window resizes
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
      // Get the height + padding + border of `#masthead`
      var mastHeight = $("#global-header-section").innerHeight();
      // Add the height to `.site-content`
      $("#et-main-area").css('margin-top', mastHeight);
    });
    // Trigger the function on document load.
    $(window).trigger('resize');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

This will ensure that the script runs correctly only once, and that any variables defined inside the closure are not accessible from outside the closure.